# How to download a image on div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uri

I append "chartdiv00" div as a image to the "imgChart1" div.

```
LoadImage = function(){
    var imgData = $('#chartdiv00').jqplotToImageStr({});
    var imgElem = $('<img/>').attr('src',imgData);
    $('#imgChart1').append(imgElem);
}
```

then what i want is to download the "imgChart1" div's image as a png or jpg by a button click. How could I do that ? 
Can I use the download attribute in HTML5 ? 
Then what is the URL of my image? 
If I can convert the image into dataURI I can dowaload it I think. Is there a way to convert this kind of image to dataURI ?

Thanks

Comment: what are you getting in imgData?

Comment: @writeToBhuwan I am using jqplot to plot graphs and I want download that graph. img Data consist with jqplot image.

Answer (score 3):

If you print the image into a `canvas` element, then you can use the `canvas.toDataURL()` to get the base64 representation of the image.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement

EDIT: Here is a quick and dirty way how to get a download link of the canvas as an image.

```
            var canvas = $('<canvas>')[0];
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.fillStyle='#f00';
            ctx.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width,canvas.height);

            var link = $('<a>').attr({
                href : canvas.toDataURL(),
                download : 'imageName',
                target : '_blank'
            }).text('download link');

            $('#Content').append(link);
```

PS. Keep in mind, that because you are using the canvas as a buffer to get the base64 code of the image you do not actually have to append it to the DOM tree. Also the jQuery is not essential, the same logic would work in pure JS as well.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer but after getting image to the canvas still i cant download the image it is downloading html file consisting nothing.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I download it?

Comment: @DilanG check out the EDIT, I used jQuery for quick coding, but you can use the same logic with pure JS as well